# JObject.Parse c#

Tags: c#, json.net

Im trying to parse my class to Json, but i have some problemas to do it like i want.

```
{     
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "Term": {
                  "number": 5
               }
            },
            {
               "Match": {
                  "name": "xxx"
               }
            }
         ]
     }         
}
```

my class is

```
    public class BaseLeafQuery
        {
            public BaseFilterType Bool { get; set; }
        }

    public class BaseFilterType 
        {
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "must", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
            public List<BaseTypeQuery> Must { get; set; }
        }
    public class BaseTypeQuery {
           [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "term", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
            public Dictionary<string, object> Term { get; set; } 
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "match", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
            public Dictionary<string, object> Match { get; set; }
    }
```

But when i convert the json becomes it

```
{     
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "Term": {
                  "number": 5
               },
               "Match": {
                  "name": "xxx"
               }
            }
         ]
     }         
}
```

Every class inside the "MUST" class must be beetween {}

Example:

```
BaseTypeQuery baseTypeQuery = new BaseTypeQuery();
            baseTypeQuery.Term = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "Id", 5 } };
            baseTypeQuery.Match = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "Email", "xxx" } };

            BaseLeafQuery leafQuery = new BaseLeafQuery();
            leafQuery.Bool = new BaseFilterType();
            leafQuery.Bool.Must = new List<BaseTypeQuery>();
            leafQuery.Bool.Must.Add(baseTypeQuery);
            var a = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(leafQuery);
```

The result of A is 
**{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"Id":5},"match":{"Email":"xxx"}}]}}**
but should bu
**{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"Id":5}},{"match":{"Email":"xxx"}}]}}**

Comment: The second JSON you posted isnt even valid JSON.

Comment: now the second JSON is correct.

Comment: What properties are "term" and "match" supposed to match with in  your JSON?

Comment: I dont' userstand. Do you serialize or deserialize?

Comment: i have to serialize. And i fix the JSON again

Comment: What you have provided I cannot reproduce it. The first json have 2 BaseTypeQuery objects but the second json you provide only have 1 BaseTypeObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have worked for me, can you confirm this is what you wanted?

```
    void Main()
{
    var a = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( "{     \"bool\": {\"must\": [{\"Term\": {\"number\": 5}},{\"Match\": {\"name\": \"xxx\"}}]}}",typeof(TestClass)).Dump();
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a).Dump();
}

public class TestClass
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "bool", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public BaseFilterType Bool { get; set; }
}

public class BaseFilterType
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "must", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<BaseTypeQuery> Must { get; set; }
}
public class BaseTypeQuery
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "term", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Term { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "match", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Match { get; set; }
}
```

Please note that I had to @bool the class because you cannot declare a class with a keyword name

The output for the serialize is

**{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"number":5}},{"match":{"name":"xxx"}}]}}**

This is the change you've been looking for I hope

```
BaseTypeQuery baseTypeQuery1 = new BaseTypeQuery();
BaseTypeQuery baseTypeQuery2 = new BaseTypeQuery();
baseTypeQuery1.Term = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "Id", 5 } };
baseTypeQuery2.Match = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "Email", "xxx" } };

BaseLeafQuery leafQuery = new BaseLeafQuery();
leafQuery.Bool = new BaseFilterType();
leafQuery.Bool.Must = new List<BaseTypeQuery>();
leafQuery.Bool.Must.Add(baseTypeQuery1);
leafQuery.Bool.Must.Add(baseTypeQuery2);
var a = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(leafQuery, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Dont use the `@` sign, just use `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "bool"]` on top of the `public BaseFilterType Bool { get; set; }`.  Also, OP should consider _not_ naming properties after reserved keywords...

Comment: True, was just staying as close as I can to the initial setting :), made the suggested change, thanks

Comment: I don't get it, when I plug your code in (assuming that **BaseLeafQuery" is actuall the **bool** class from the example), I don't have a definition for **baseQuery**, without that line I get **{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"Id":5},"match":{"Email":"xxx"}}]}}**. So either something is missing or we're not using the same objects as you presented initially.

Comment: sorry, the baseQuery i have puted it wrong. And you are right the BaseLeafQuery is the bool from example

Comment: no worries but are we using the same classes as at the top?

Comment: Found the issue, in the initial JSON you have 2 must clauses where as in your code you only add one that contains both the Term and the Match, for you to have it like in the initial JSON you need to add the separately to the "Must"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154815/discussion-between-vnvizitiu-and-mauricio-bueno).